# How to create base class for custom views in Android using Kotlin?

Tags: android, generics, kotlin

I want to create a base class for all of my custom views. It can be a different type, for example, `RelativeLayout` or `NavigationView`.

So I've created `abstract class` with generics which is implementing the deepest class of these views which is connecting them - `View`. This is what I've got:

```
abstract class MyCustomView<VS : ViewState, V : View<VS>, P : Presenter<VS, V, *>>(
context: Context,
attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
defStyleAttr: Int = 0,
defStyleRes: Int = 0
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes) { ... }
```

But the problem is that now I'm able to inherit only from the `View`. How can I build somehow generic that must be a child of the `View` so I could implement it and still to be able inside my base class to `override` methods like `onAttachedToWindow`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare your class like this:

```
abstract class MyCustomView<VS : ViewState, V : View<VS>, P : Presenter<VS, V, *>>() : View{ 

 constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int, defStyleRes: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)



(...)
 }
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't think that will solve my problem. I don't have a problem with `constructor` while I have declared default values so I choose if I want to pass anything more than `Context`. The problem is that I still can't have one, parent class for all the custom views which can be specified type, for example, `NavigationView` so I could use methods from itself. At this moment when I change my custom view to implement my base class, there's no way to get methods from specified `View`.